# Task Scheduler C# on a remote server

Tags: c#, com, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to get all task scheduled from a remote server.
I use TaskScheduler 1.1 Type Library that is a COM reference.
There is what i tried :

```
TaskSchedulerClass ts = new TaskSchedulerClass();
ts.Connect(Current_Server, username, domain, password);
IRunningTaskCollection tasks = ts.GetRunningTasks(1);
Console.WriteLine(tasks.Count.ToString());

foreach (IRunningTask task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
}
```

This run but i didn't get any task in the console.

An another way i tried is using this wrapper : http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Here is the code i use for this solution :

```
class Task_Get_All_Task
{
    public void EnumAllTasks()
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            EnumFolderTasks(ts.RootFolder);
    }

    private void EnumFolderTasks(TaskFolder fld)
    {
        foreach (Task task in fld.Tasks)
            ActOnTask(task);
        foreach (TaskFolder sfld in fld.SubFolders)
            EnumFolderTasks(sfld);
    }

    private void ActOnTask(Task t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

With this one i got all task on my own workstation but i dont know how to use it on a remote server.

Comment: You are accessing the running tasks only, with GetRunningTasks. But it seems that you want to access all registered tasks
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/index/aa446864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

Comment: I just want to get ALL scheduled Tasks to get their name and description in a .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

I was using it the wrong way ... my bad

This work :

```
var ts = new TaskService(Server, username, domain, password);
foreach (Task task in ts.RootFolder.Tasks)
{
   //do things
}
```